# SWIG binary TypeError on list input

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, swig

I'm getting a TypeError from a SWIG C++ -> python 3.6 binary. It is a simple C wrapper for a class method, I've simplified to eliminate all surface STL stuff.

```
swig -version
SWIG Version 3.0.12

cmake --version
cmake version 3.15.2

python --version
Python 3.6.9

clang++ --version
clang version 10.0.0 (trunk 375507)
```

The error is

```
In [12]: import proto                                                                                                                                              

In [13]: a = [1.1]*10                                                                                                                                               

In [14]: b = [2.0] * 10                                                                                                                                             

In [15]: proto.find_path(10, 5, a, b)                                                                                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-bec8cb507a9b> in <module>
----> 1 _proto.find_path(10, 5, a, b)

TypeError: in method 'find_path', argument 3 of type 'float []'
```

Implementation:

python_graph.hpp:

```
#ifndef __PYTHON_GRAPH_HPP__
#define __PYTHON_GRAPH_HPP__

int* find_path(int, int, float[], float[]);

#endif
```

python_graph.cpp

```
#include "python_graph.hpp"
#include "graph.hpp"

int* find_path(int n, int T, float a[], float b[]) {

  auto pg = PartitionGraph(n, T, a, b);
  return pg.get_optimal_path_extern();

}
```

proto.i:

```
/* File : proto.i */
%module proto

%{
#include "python_graph.hpp"
#include "graph.hpp"
%}

%include "python_graph.hpp"
```

I am building with cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

project(proto)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonInterp REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)

include(UseSWIG)
# set(UseSWIG TARGET_NAME_PREFERENCE STANDARD)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})

set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

add_library(graph OBJECT graph.cpp)

# C++ executable
add_executable(proto main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(proto graph)

# SWIG bindings
set_source_files_properties(proto.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
set_source_files_properties(proto.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall")
swig_add_library(proto LANGUAGE python SOURCES python_graph.cpp graph.cpp proto.i)
swig_link_libraries(proto ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

The cmake build also builds a stand-alone working C++ executable, the trouble comes when wrapping with SWIG. I've tried a bunch of stuff, I'm not sure what SWIG is expecting, can't find anything in the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It seems like it's easier to work with stl containers directly, just change the function signature and the above interface file to

```
/* File : proto.i */
%module proto

%{
#include "graph.hpp"
#include "python_graph.hpp"
%}

%include "std_vector.i"
namespace std {
%template(IArray) vector<int>;
%template(FArray) vector<float>;
}

%include "python_graph.hpp"
```

the list can then be defined in python as

```
a = proto.FArray()
a = [1.4]*10
```

etc.